# Error on "Online Customers" page: Call to a member function getBackendType() on a non-object

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, customer, error, collection

I getting this error for my online collection tab on Magento. 1.9.1

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackendType() on a
>   non-object in
>   /home/*****/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Resource/Visitor/Online/Collection.php
>   on line 72

I can usually figure this out, but I don't know much about the online customers tab in Magento. It started happening when we went to our 4 server cluster a couple months ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getBackendType()` is called on `$attribute`:

```
$attribute = $customer->getAttribute($attributeCode);
```

Where `$attributeCode` is "lastname", "firstname" or "email". These attributes seem to be missing from the `eav_attributes` table, please check if they have been accidently deleted.

Comment: Getting this attribute thing.It was missing. Just re built the tables with a little work and it worked perfect! Led me on to many other areas too. Thanks for the help!